# Calculating Pi with C++; Where am I messing up?

Tags: c++, runtime-error, infinite-loop, pi

for fun I am trying to calculate pi using the well-known algorithm that:
pi/4 = 1 - (1/3) + (1/5) - (1/7) + (1/9), etc....
Then multiplying the resultant by 4 to get pi (approximately).
I've spent the last 45 minutes or so writing and trying to get this code to work.  Where am I messing up?  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
//I'm new, which of these are necessary in this program?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
//1.0 as 1/4 pi is used as part of the algorithm in the for loop
float pi_fourth = 1.0;
//to be used as a counter inside for loop
int i = 5;
//I want the for loop to stop after only a few iterations
for (pi_fourth = 1.000000; i < 20 ; i + 4)
{
    //algorithm for determining one-fourth pi
    // algorithm is pi/4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9, etc...
    (pi_fourth -= 1/i) += (1/(i-2));
}
//now to complete the program, I need to multiply result
//  of the for loop to get pi approx.
float real_pi = (pi_fourth * 4);
//final print statement to reveal pi to a few digits
cout << "pi is ABOUT " << endl << real_pi << endl;
return 0;
}
```

When it runs, no errors come out, it just never gets to the final print statement, which leads me to believe this is an infinite loop.  Is that a correct assumption?  I apologize if the answer is extremely simple; as I mentioned before, I'm new to C++.

Comment: `for (pi_fourth = 1.000000; i < 20 ; i + 4)` i + 4 does nothing so you have an infinite loop since i never changes.

Comment: `for (pi_fourth = 1.000000; i < ; i + 4)` what about some reasonable stop condition ?

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger

Comment: [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7ae3994f35543d1): *warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]* with squiggles under `i + 4`.

Comment: Isn't i + 4 an increment statement?  And Severin, I just copied into the window incorrectly, it's fixed now.

Comment: Never seen such a notation `(pi_fourth -= 1/i) += (1/(i-2));`, I'm wondering that this works. However won't apply here an integer division?

Comment: Ahh, thank you Severin

Comment: @rekire:  Would there be a better way to write this?

Comment: @rekire, Assignment expressions return the thing being assigned a new value, so it's valid. It would probably be more readable as two statements, though.

Comment: I never used C++ productively so I'm not the best person to ask but I would write it as `pi_fourth -= 1/(i*1.0) + 1/(i-2.0);`

Comment: @rekire, It's a reference to the LHS, so you can chain them as you can with `a = b = c`.

Comment: Every programmer [no matter how experienced] makes [as you say] "idiotic" mistakes.  Always compile with `-Wall` and `-Werror`.  Your `i + 4` would have been flagged by `g++`.  `clang` just turns on more warnings by default.

Comment: Thanks, Craig.  I'll Google -Wall, -Werror, g++, and clang.  I appreciate the direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a fixed version of the program with comments:

```
#include <iostream>
// Only iostream is needed for cout and endl.
// using namespace std is usually not recommended on global scope

int main()
{
    float pi_fourth = 1.0;
    int i = 3;
    for(; i < 1000; i += 4)
    {
        // pi_fourth was already initialized. using 1.00000 instead of 1.0 has no effect.
        // i += 4 to add to i
        // fixed the algorithm, and wrote it in two statements.
        // 1.0/i instead of 1/i, otherwise it would be an integer division (because both 1 and i are integers).
        pi_fourth -= 1.0/i;
        pi_fourth += 1.0/(i + 2);
    }
    float real_pi = pi_fourth * 4.0;
    std::cout << "pi is ABOUT " << std::endl << real_pi << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @tmlen:
Thanks so much, you've taught me a bunch in just a couple of minutes!  From how std (or any other "using X") works, how to make sure to multiply by floats instead of integers so as to keep the result as a float.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (pi_fourth = 1.000000; i < 20 ; i + 4)
```

`i` it's not incremented. Try

```
for (pi_fourth = 1.000000; i < 20 ; i += 4)
```

Comment: That helps a lot.  At least now this isn't an infinite loop.  That's the only thing I dislike about programming; my mistakes tend to be completely idiotic.

Answer (score 3):

Here some thoughts on the matter, not quite related to the bugs in the code

In sign-changing series error is no more than last dropped term. So typical approach is to ask user for the required precision and from that compute how many terms to sum denoted `N`.

It should be summed starting from smallest term toward largest one, that way you keep rounding errors small and under control. So loop shall look like

```
for(int i = N; i > 0; i -= 2)
```

It is preferable to add one term per one loop cycle, somewhere along the lines

```
double sign = 1.0;
double pi = 0.0;
for(int i = N; i > 0; i -= 2) {
    auto term = sign / double(i);
    pi += term;
    sign = -sign;
}

return fabs(pi); // might be negative value
```